# Error TS2741 ("property... is missing in type") being caused by the existence of a method

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

I created the following example code to minimally reproduce my problem:

```
class Test {
  prop1 : boolean
  prop2 : string

  method() { }

  static create(prop1 : boolean, prop2 : string) : Test {
    let item : Test = {
      prop1: prop1,
      prop2: prop2
    }

    return item;
  }
}
```

Note that the equivalent to `create` in my actual code is a factory method that might return an instance of a child class (which is why I chose to make this a static method instead of a constructor).

Unfortunately, for this code, I get the following compile error:

> error TS2741: Property 'method' is missing in type '{ prop1: boolean; prop2: string; }' but required in type 'Test'.

When I hover over `method` in Visual Studio Code, Intellisense correctly lists it as a method, *not* a property. However, the error message (incorrectly) states that it's a property.

I tried reading the following Q&As, but they didn't help me:

[error TS2741: Property is missing in type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56626749/error-ts2741-property-is-missing-in-type) - the accepted answer talks about the type of the parameter that the method accepts, but the method in my MRE doesn't accept a parameter

[How to fix "Property 'type' is missing in type but required in type 'SeriesXrangeOptions'" in angular highcharts module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54670687/how-to-fix-property-type-is-missing-in-type-but-required-in-type-seriesxrang) - solution appears to be unrelated to my problem

[Typescript / Angular 2: Property is missing in type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40377558/typescript-angular-2-property-is-missing-in-type) - that one was caused by improperly implementing an interface, but I'm not implementing an interface

Can someone explain why I'm getting this error and how I could fix it?

Comment: You need to use `new` to create instances of classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some options to do that:

1. You can use `interface` for that:

   ```
    static create(prop1 : boolean, prop2 : string) : Test 
    {
      let item : myInterface = {
        prop1: prop1,
        prop2: prop2
      }

     return item as Test;
   }
   ```

[Here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=19&ssc=5&pln=12&pc=4#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLYE8CS5ryQbwChkSAHKAe1IEZkAuZAIwooBsI4QAaYsy0gEz1kAZzBRQAcx4BfQoQSs4IkcgAqEMcmCpS7VBHCqM2SLEQoifKrQbM2HEMgC8yeKxERe5KkIZiJEEkXZAAiUPkSAzAACwoAEwAKAEpkfGQ5XlEwODBgBGQEKA5IRJ8aYXt2Ti5kcr9swMlUhg0tKxISdjBtSFRhExxzJBCOzusaBnLqHnHO%20qn%20ASySTLnisABXKCdgPuRldU0wAG4suUyANzgoZB7XEAgAdyOxFLOFChARBwA6VgokkSbTAvyKJQgiXEmwgtVCkDEoWSyROQA) is working example.

2. Use `new` keyword and `constructor`:

   ```
    static create(prop1 : boolean, prop2 : string) : Test {
        let item = new Test(prop1,prop2);

        return item;
      }
   ```

Or maybe partially call `constructor` like that:

```
    public constructor(init?:Partial<Test>) {
        Object.assign(this, init);
    }
```

[Here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAqCmEAu0DeAoa0AOAnA9tgIzQBc0ARvviPGAHbQC80AZmCBPJjgdgExloyXAEt6Ac2bQARDJ5YF0APQAqJdgCuFEKODRg+eiM3Ak+XAApxopAH5SABTC4kojgB4EyAHwBKNCUsLAB5CgAreDMAOkgIUQl6SyQAC1EIABpoGyQ-AG4lAF9VZXQeQ2MkXFNzK2JSKho6eiyBUhFxCT8MYOhU9Oi8QhIWYgLe-ohBvkFR-nHoQrKsAFt4VPwAE0sA1EXl4SQwN31gXDokeEsh4iFG2gZWmaEOyQDybxQe4NoUW3gVtJ6PAAO5wRBIa58IgZG78fJKZTKX7ZS6AljAsGfSyoG4wuGFfJI1gWaBhSIxOIJJKTLI5BFKc5ITS4Rj-FYLJZLdAVCBNaIgfASSyfaJnC5XdiceAZGSXZAyPx+IA) is working example